# C language: memory allocation of a structure of two char* pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, char

I need to allocate a structure of two pointers to char, as follows:

```
typedef struct message_s {
    char* message;
    char* sender_id; 
} message_t;
```

"message" will be a pointer to a char[] of 246 bytes;

"sender_id" will be a pointer to a char[] of 3 bytes;

What is the correct way to allocate memory for the message_t type?
So far, my solution is the following, but it looks like it doesn't work.

```
message_t* msg = NULL;
char* a_message = (char*)malloc((size_t)246);
a_message = /*read the string somewhere*/
char* id = (char*)malloc((size_t)3);
id = /*read the string somewhere*/
msg->message = a_message;
msg->sender_id = id;
```

This leads to a segmentation fault. May i need to allocate the memory for the message_t ? How?

Comment: `msg = malloc(sizeof *msg);`

Comment: If you know the exact sizes of your `char` arrays, why use pointers in the `struct` in the first place?

Comment: and notice type names with `_t` suffix are reserved in POSIX, so it might be better not to use them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Felix, i'm using pointers because i want to manage different lenghts for the messages. You are right, the question was specific to just a portion of code and i didn't said it explicitly.

Comment: Also, i didn't know suffix _t was reserved to POSIX, thanks for the info.

Comment: Yes, managing different lengths is very easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pseudo-code has *memory leaks*, e.g.

```
char* a_message = (char*)malloc((size_t)246);
a_message = /*read the string somewhere*/
```

This would overwrite the pointer `a_message`, so it does no longer point to the memory reserved by `malloc()` in the previous line. Therefore you can't ever `free()` this memory.

From all that's shown in your question, there's no reason to use pointers at all. You could just declare your struct like this:

```
typedef struct message
{
    char message[246];
    char sender_id[3];
} message;
```

and allocate it as a whole like this:

```
message *msg = malloc(sizeof *msg);
```

Before using it, check that `msg` isn't `NULL`, `malloc()` can fail ...

---

With pointers, you have to allocate three individual chunks:

```
typedef struct message
{
    char *message;
    char *sender_id;
} message;

// ...

// no error checking here for brevity, add the checks yourself:
message *msg = malloc(sizeof *msg);
msg->message = malloc(246);
msg->sender_id = malloc(3);
```

Comment: The solution with no pointers at all looks the more reasonable. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
message_t* msg = malloc(sizeof(message_t));
```

Or just allocate it on the stack:

```
message_t msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "a_message" and "id" pointers point to memories that already allocated. Essentially pointer is an argument that stores a memory address with some data type. But the msg is NULL, that is to say msg points to an invalid space. So when you want to give msg->message a value, the program tries to access an illegal add ress. That's why segment fault. To solve the issue, you need to give msg a valid space to store msg->message and msg->sender_id. That's why "message_t* msg = malloc(sizeof(message_t));" is necessary.